Proving $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3}$ is rational
Problem: Show that $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}$
My approach
By definition, $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q} \iff \exists n,m \in \mathbb{Z}: \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3} = \frac{n}{m}$
Carrying out the algebra, we get:
$m\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} = n+m\sqrt{3} \implies m^2(4+2\sqrt{3}) = n^2 + 2nm\sqrt{3} + 3m^2$
$\implies m^2 + (2m^2-2mn)\sqrt{3} - n^2 = 0$
We need to find integer solutions for $m,n$ to show that this expression evaluates to a rational number. In this case, we can choose $m=n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so we have the equivalency class $\{1\}$ as the set of values for $m,n$ that solve this equation..
Is this a valid proof or am I making an implicit assumptions or not checking a condition?

Edit on completing the above proof
So I conferred with a mathematics professor, and he confirmed my reasoning is valid, but incomplete. In my above proof, I square the expressions in one of my steps, which introduces extraneous solutions (i.e., my steps are not reversible).
Therefore, all I have shown is that $1$ may be the value of $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3}$. The proof now requires me to show that, indeed, $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3} =1$.
Thankfully, this is an easy final check:
$$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3} = 1 \implies  \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} =1+ \sqrt{3} \implies 4+2\sqrt{3} = 1+2\sqrt{3} + 3 = 4+2\sqrt{3}$$
$\square$

You are showing $m=n$ already implies the required expression is $1$. More likely, the last step you doing only implies that you try to verify $m=n$ is a solution of your equaiton $m^2+(2m^2-2mn)\sqrt{3}-n^2=0$, but not related to original statement.

@AngaeMT but if there exists m,n (integers) such that the equation has a solution then doesn't the original expression evaluate to a rational number? I got the equation by applying the definition of a rational number to the expression.

@SassatelliGiulio apologies, but I have several $\implies$ in here. Could you be more direct? What I think I have shown is that $\sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}=1 \in \mathbb{Q}$

@SassatelliGiulio I still don't get the issues, m=n does solve the equation. The last line is exactly this check -- as long as we pick m and n to be the same integer we get a valid solution, so it is rational and, specifically, it evaluates to 1.

@SassatelliGiulio last line - I show that, indeed, we can find a pair of integers that solves the equation.

@OnTheWay -- there may have been a formatting error - can't read your comment

${m^2} + (2{m^2} - 2mn)\sqrt 3  - {n^2} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \left( {m - n} \right)\left( {2\sqrt 3 m + m + n} \right) = 0$ then you can show that $n=m$ or $n=m(-1-2\sqrt{3})$ which leads to $n/m=1$.

@SassatelliGiulio sorry, I really don't get this green/blue thing. Can you write an answer showing where this went off the rails and what I'm missing?

No, I generally prefer not to write answers on this site.

@OnTheWay didn't I do that? By inspection, we can see that if $n=m$ it solves the equation.

For a systematic approach, see Strategies to denest nested radicals $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}$

The OP shows, if the expression equals $n/m$, then the pair $m,n$ is a solution to  $() , m^2 + (2m^2-2mn)\sqrt{3} - n^2 = 0$.  You need to converse, if the pair $m,n$ is a solution to  $()$ then the original expression equals $n/m.$ The implications need to be reversed. As an extra: The converse shows $(*)$ only has solutions $m=n.$

$$\left( ~1 + \sqrt{3} ~\right)^2 = 4 + 2\sqrt{3} \implies $$
$$\sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt{3}} = 1 + \sqrt{3}.$$

The above analysis has the defect of being an answer rather than a (derived) solution.
Suppose
$$\left( a + b\sqrt{3} ~\right)^2 = 4 + 2\sqrt{3}.$$
Then $~2ab = 2~$ and $~a^2 + 3b^2 = 4.$
This implies that
$$b = \frac{1}{a} \implies a^2 + \frac{3}{a^2} = 4.$$
This implies that
$$a^4 - 4a^2 + 3 = 0 \implies (a^2 - 3) \times (a^2 - 1) = 0.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

$$\implies m^2 + (2m^2-2mn)\sqrt{3} - n^2 = 0$$

If $~r~$ and $~s~$ are integers and
$$r + s\sqrt{3} = 0,$$
then $~r = 0~$ and $~s = 0.$
So, the original poster's approach, up to the excerpted line above is viable.
You end up with $~m = n~$ which implies that
$$\sqrt{4 + \sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3} = 1, \tag1 $$
from which the problem can be completed by an alternative route.
As a clarification, (1) above does not prove that $~m = n.~$  Instead, it proves that if $~\displaystyle \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3}~$ is rational, then it must be equal to $~1.$

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Suppose $$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3}=r \notin \mathbb{Q}\;\;\;(*)$$
Particulary, this means $r\ne 1$. Then $$4+2\sqrt{3} = (r+\sqrt{3})^2$$
so $$4+2\sqrt{3} = 3+2r\sqrt{3}+r^2$$
so  $$2\sqrt{3}(1-r) = r^2-1$$
Since $r$ can not be $1$ we have $$r= -2\sqrt{3}-1$$
But then if we plugg this in  $(*)$ we get
$$  \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} = -\sqrt{3}-1<0$$
A contradiction.

Thanks! Didn't I implicitly do this by solving for m,n as integers? That fact that I could even find a solution implies the expression is rational.

Your aproach is not correct since you used the fact you have yet to prove.

Isn't it only circular if we don't have a biconditional? An expression is only rational iff we can find integers that it satisfies.

I don't understand your last question.

I used the definition of rationality -- if we can find integers that solve the equation I found, that means that the original expression is rational due to the iff statement at the beginning. If the expression were not rational, then I would not have been able to find any integer solultions.

user2661923 has answer you perfectly where upvote stands in a comments of his answer

I'm not sure about that -- I only assumed that it is rational iff it satisfies the equation I derived. It did, hence it is rational.

I'm sorry i can not help you. By

It's ok -- I'm almost certainly wrong but I need to clearly see why

@Annika you proved that if the number is rational, it is equal to 1. However, you did not prove  the converse. You can see that when you use $\implies$ in your algebra and not $\iff$

This is exactly $1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}=&\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt3^2+2\times1\times\sqrt3}\\
=&\sqrt{(1+\sqrt3)^2}\\
=&1+\sqrt3
\end{align}
$$

Because m and n are integers, you can find that $m = n$ by equalizing all the coefficients.
$$m^2(4+2\sqrt{3}) = n^2 + 2nm\sqrt{3} + 3m^2$$
$$4m^2+2m^2\sqrt{3} = 3m^2 + n^2 + 2mn\sqrt{3}$$
Then:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 4m^2=3m^2+n^2 \\ 2m^2=2mn \end{matrix}\right.$$
implying that $m = n$.
Bonus: You can also do the same thing starting from the equation that you get. Because the RHS is 0, all the coefficients from the LHS should be 0 as well.
